# git stash pop fails when swap file is deleted

Tags: git

I deleted a swap file and called `git stash` before making a pull request. When i tried `git stash pop`, i got following error

> Cannot apply to a dirty working tree, please stage your changes

I followed this [wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360712/git-stash-cannot-apply-to-a-dirty-working-tree-please-stage-your-changes) and tried to apply via patching the changes. But it is not working.

I guess this message will give some hint

```
diff --git a/db/.schema.rb.swp b/db/.schema.rb.swp
deleted file mode 100644
index 6570b8e..0000000
Binary files a/db/.schema.rb.swp and /dev/null differ
```

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You **SHOULD NOT** commit the swap file into git repository. Try to follow the instructions:

```
git rm db/.schema.rb.swp   # Delete the swap file from git repository
echo "*.swp" >> .gitignore # Ignore swap files
git add .gitignore
git commit                 # Commit the deletion & changes
git status                 # Make sure that you have no uncommited changes
git stash apply            # Then apply the stash
```