# Git stash pop with binary - merge conflict

Tags: git, git-stash, merge-conflict-resolution

I'm trying to do a "git stash pop" with a binary file.  It results in a merge conflict.  I just want to pull what's in the stash off and overwrite what's in the working directory.  What is the easiest way to do that?

Comment: Not sure if it's a duplicate exactly, but [this answer might help you](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3733698/2812842)

Comment: Hmm... well, the working branch (or the file in question) isn't dirty.  It was just changed in another branch before being merged in, and the file in the stash doesn't have the merged in changes.

Comment: It's a suggested method for using a `--force` approach to `git stash pop` - give it a try anyway :)

Answer (score 20):

To restore all files to their stashed version:

```
$ git checkout stash -- .
```

Comment: Results in detached head, doesn't return to the pre-stashed state.

Comment: This was a great tip.  I had a merge conflict on a binary file when un-stashing and I could not figure out how to take the stashed version of the binary file.

Comment: Got the same problem with a docx document, this checkout worked great. Thanks.

Comment: Finally something that does the trick! The common `git stash apply` doesn't really work with binary files. Thanks!