# cannot resolving a merge conflict manually befor stashing pop

Tags: git, gitlab, git-merge

I'd like pulling rebase from master to my origin branch.So I follow these steps:

1. I stached my changes
2. I have pulled with rebase from master
3. I poped my stash changes

But I encounter a problem when poping changes and it seems like I have a conflict merges in file `scdf.mv.db`.That's output of `git status`:

```
On branch master Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Unmerged paths:   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)   (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)

        both modified:   proactive-policy-task/scdf.mv.db 

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

So for resolving this issue I proceeded by merging conflict manually of `scdf.mv.db` file. So I opened it with vim in order to `HEAD` Tag or `<<<<<<<` marker but I didn't found nothing.

Note that the file that giving me a headache this morning is binary.

I have tried merging conflict by using merge tools like `kdiff3`. So I have choosed C EveryWhere, but without success (the same problem when choosing A or B). Also I have tried to delete it but it occurs the same thing.

For further information, when I run `git stash pop` after using `kdiff3`, it shows me this error:

```
warning: Cannot merge binary files: proactive-policy-task/scdf.mv.db (Updated upstream vs. Stashed changes) Auto-merging proactive-policy-task/scdf.mv.db CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in proactive-policy-task/scdf.mv.db
```

Comment: You can't merge a binary file (without *very* specialized tools), pick one or the other.

Answer (score 1):

As commented, you need to choose between:

- the [stashed version of that file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29979963/6309):

  ```
  git checkout stash -- path/to/file
  ```
- the one from your branch

  ```
  git checkout -- path/to/file
  ```

In any case, add and commit. Your status should then be clean.

Comment: Or, if you don't want to add and commit your version of changed files at this point, after you performed one of the two `git checkout` suggested above, do a `git stash drop` if you no longer need the stashed files and then `git reset`.

Comment: @dolphin Indeed, that would work too.