# Is there a way I can intentionally cause a merge conflict with a file inside my stash?

Tags: git, git-stash

I have a single SCSS file inside my stash, a few stashes back. Let's call it `target.scss`. It is the only file therein and contains a small handful of modified selectors.

I have since modified `target.scss`.

What I'd *like* to do is `git merge stash@{2}` (its location), and have git treat it like any other merge. That is to say, I *want* Git to report a conflict, so I can resolve the conflict then `git add`, commit, and push.

I know there are other ways to do this. Yes, I can commit and apply. Yes, I can spin up a new branch, apply and rebase. Or even merge. But I'm hoping to avoid the need to commit prior to performing the merge.

Does a pattern exist in which I can trigger a merge from my stash into my presently-dirty HEAD, handle the merge conflicts, and then commit as though I'd simply manually merged them?

I can *diff* the file with a `git diff stash@{2} target.scss`, but I cannot work out how to put git into "merge conflict" mode to resolve same. Should I be looking at `diff` instead of `merge`?

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3733698/3001761?

Comment: I have not come across that specific answer before, no, although that certainly seems at first glance very similar to what I'm looking to do. Just a tick; lemme try it!

Comment: Hmmmm.... close. I'm getting a `target.scss:  does not match index`... though I suspect this is due to the fact that either A: I have heavily modified the file since it was stashed, OR B: because it's an older stash. I had to modify the show command to `git stash show -p stash@{2}` as well. I'll tinker with the `apply` and see if I can't induce a force of some flavor.

Comment: @jonrsharpe That was mighty close. I'm not 100% certain it's doable, based on the issue I was having (namely, the patch was unwilling to apply to the target file due to an inability to locate certain landmark strings therein). I'm inferring that this would make a merge with conflicts equally improbable. I DID figure out a way to bully it into performing the merge, which in this case was a mere concatenation of both files. In this specific instance, awesome; it's what I'd wanted the outcome to be, but it's still not entirely what I'd been hoping for. Thank you for the guidance! It helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering this, but all credit goes to [jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe), who pointed me to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3733698/3001761) from [muhqu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/450383) which came very close to offering me an answer; I just needed to tweak it a bit.

The other answer suggested:

```
git stash show -p | git apply -3 && git stash drop
```

This is close to what I'd wanted, although it would:

1. Merge the wrong stash,
2. Fail in its application of same, and then
3. Delete the newer stash (which I'd not wanted involved to begin with), and
4. It doesn't induce merge conflicts. It behaves as though I'd told it to "accept both", file-wide.

To resolve these issues:

1. Let's change the target stash:

   ```
   git stash show -p stash@{2} # This will select the stash 2 nodes back, 
                               # and create a patch from it.
   ```
2. Because it's an older stash, I needed to reduce the strictness of the patch's willingness to apply. This can be done by amending a `-C1` flag to the `git apply` statement. So:

   ```
   git apply -3 -C1
   ```

   This is essentially telling Git, "So long as *any line* within this file matches, presuppose it's a valid application. Attempt to merge using a 3-way merge. Fall back to a vanilla merge otherwise."
3. I *don't* wish to drop the relevant stash, so I'll just omit the `&& git stash drop`

In this particular case, I *did* want to accept all from both. But my search for inducing a traditional conflict continues.

Comment: Your question gives relevant details on the commands you have tried, however I still have a hard time understanding what changes you actually want to get from that `stash@{2}` entry. Can you please explain what changes you intend to port back from your stash ? note that, when stashing, you can have some staged changes _and_ some unstaged changes in one file, is that a specific issue in your case ? or do you want to apply "all the changes that were on file `target.scss`" anyway ?

Comment: one point: you don't _need_ a conflict to edit changes after the facts, `git apply` has applied changes on the staging area (not created a commit), you are free to edit the changes however you see fit before `git add`ing again and committing. Other commands such as `git merge` or `git cherry-pick` have a `--no-commit` option, which also allows you to edit changes before committing.